# Add an icon to pop-up in Terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

Essentially, I want to add an icon to a pop-up alert prompt from Terminal. Here is the code:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Text: " default answer "")'
```

To give you an example, when you are prompted with a password window, there is a Lock icon in the window. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an icon to an AppleScript dialog you could use:

```
with icon file "path:to:icon.icns"
```

Where path is the location and filename (icons can be `.png`, etc.), so you would end up with:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Text: " default answer "" with icon file "path:to:icon.icns")'
```

Comment: I tried the following:   `osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Text: " default answer "" with icon file "~/Desktop/icon.icns")'` It doesn't work though it says: "File file ~/Desktop/icon.icns wasn’t found" even though icon.icns is on my Desktop. @l'L'l

Comment: You need to use a POSIX path in the form of `Volume:Users:Username:Desktop:icon.icns`, or use something like this since it's on your desktop `with icon ((path to desktop as text) & "icon.icns") as alias`

Comment: @natojato: You could also do `with icon ((path to home folder as text) & "Desktop:icon.icns") as alias`, which you start off in the `~/` home directory and you specify the rest of the path with `"directory:file"`...

Comment: `osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to text returned of (display dialog "Hello World" default answer "" with icon ((~/Users/user) & "Desktop:icon.icns"))'` but its says "syntax error: Expected expression, “)”"

Comment: You're doing it wrong — you cannot use paths that way in AppleScript. If you copied the example I put in both comments it should have worked (if your file is named `icon.icns` and is on the user's `Desktop`). (eg. `osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Text: " default answer "" with icon ((path to home folder as text) & "Desktop:icon.icns") as alias  )'`).